# Pie menu in decal machine addon isn't showing up correctly

Tags: add-on, pie-menu

Well, I'm creating some 3D model and I wanted to add some cool details using decal machine addon. Well, I added one decal and then I wanted to add another decal, but someting went wrong, because pie menu isn't showing up correctly.

Like this:
[image]

Comment: Sometimes add-ons bug out. You should try re-launching blender and disabling then reenabling the add-on

Comment: Since Decal Machine is a paid add-on, I would recommend that you go to their web site (https://machin3.io/DECALmachine/docs/#support) and ask for support there.

Comment: Turn off your internet. Then try again after restarting blender